# Python: Parsing data by values in multiple columns

Tags: python

This is probably a really simple question, but I'm hoping someone can provide me with a quick and efficient answer... I'm trying to enter chromosomal data into a database while changing the format somewhat. The data currently looks like:

```
chrom   = chr1
txStart = 134212702 
exonCount = 8
exonStarts = 134212702,134221529,134222782,134224273,134224707,134226534,134227135,134227897,
exonEnds=   134213049,134221650,134222806,134224425,134224773,134226654,134227268,134229870,
```

I'm creating a database with all the above data including info for Promoter, exon and intron location. Each set of data (coming from a single row such as in the sample above) would correspond to single transcript. I define a promoter as the txStart (ex. 134212702) - 2000. Each transcript with then have a set amount of exons as specified in the exon count (ex. 8). The start and end of each exon within the larger transcript is specified by matching values in the exonStarts and exonEnds list. For example the first exon in this case would range from 134212702 to 134213049. The introns are located between the exons so that the first exon would go from 134213050 to 134221528. I successfully accomplished this doing:

```
PromoterStart = int(TxStart) - 2000
PromoterEnd = int(TxStart) -1
ExonStart = map(int, ExonStart[:-1].split(","))
ExonEnd = map(int, ExonEnd[:-1].split(","))
i = 0
while i < int(ExonCount):
    ExonCount = i +1
    if i != int(ExonCount) -1:
        IntronStart[i] = ExonEnd[i] +1
        IntronEnd[i] = ExonStart[i+1] -1
    i += 1
```

Using this method I then inserted all the data into a database for later comparisons. I would now like to redo this analysis using a promoter definition going from TxStart -2000 to TxStart + 2000. However, it seems that having a large amount of overlap between the exons and promoters using this code and just changing the promoter end to  = int(TxStart) +2000, slows down my downstream analysis considerably. I would like to find a way so that if a region is considered a promoter from txStart -2000 to txStart +2000, this region would not be considered as an exon region.

Comment: I read your question twice and I fear I have no idea what you are asking. :-( Could you re-pose without all the genetic(?) specialist vocabulary obscuring what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes it is genetic stuff, but I really don't understand what you are trying to achieve. I think we need to know what your database format is because I think you try to include data from a previous gene ??? Could you please rephrase this question around the exact core of your problem.

Comment: @RickyA: I tried to rephrase and clarify my question. Each row of data corresponds to a single gene/transcript and contains all the information I need for the analysis. More specifically, I'm looking at several smaller fractions of a much larger region.

Comment: You do not use `PromoterStart` or `PromoterEnd` anywhere in the code shown and your `while` runs for the same `NumExon`. Not sure if `PromoterEnd = int(TxStart)+2000` is causing the issue here. maybe the problem lies with some other part of the code?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
NewExonStart,NewExonEnd = zip(*filter(lambda y:not(y[0]>=PromoterStart and y[1]<=PromoterEnd),zip(ExonStart,ExonEnd)))
```

You zip through pairs of `ExonStart,ExonEnd` and discard any entries that may have `ExonStart,ExonEnd` lie between `PromoterStart,PromoterEnd`. Then unzipp the zipped list to get back new values

Example

```
>>> TxStart = 134212702 
>>> PromoterStart = int(TxStart) - 2000
>>> PromoterEnd = int(TxStart) + 2000
>>> PromoterStart
134210702
>>> PromoterEnd
134214702
>>>
>>> ExonStart
[134212702, 134221529, 134222782, 134224273, 134224707, 134226534, 134227135, 134227897]
>>> ExonEnd
[134213049, 134221650, 134222806, 134224425, 134224773, 134226654, 134227268, 134229870]
>>>
>>> NewExonStart,NewExonEnd = zip(*filter(lambda y:not(y[0]>=PromoterStart and y[1]<=PromoterEnd),zip(ExonStart,ExonEnd)))
>>>
>>> NewExonStart
(134221529, 134222782, 134224273, 134224707, 134226534, 134227135, 134227897)
>>> NewExonEnd
(134221650, 134222806, 134224425, 134224773, 134226654, 134227268, 134229870)
```

The first entry of both `ExonStart` and `ExonEnd` is removed as it lies between `PromoterStart` and `PromoterEnd`

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful but this still doesn't fully answer my problem. For in this case since the promoter end falls between two exons this would be within the first intron. I would now need to change the intron start so that it would only begin after the promoter end. Or in the case where it falls within an exon I would need to change the start position of the exon so that the new start postion would be promoterEnd +1.

Comment: If you could show a couple of examples it would help in better understanding of the problem. Also not familiar with Inron, Exon or Promoter so terms like `start`,`end` and `fall in` tend to be confusing